# how can I check whether other people in my contacts are using my app or not? Ionic 2

Tags: cordova, typescript, ionic2

I want to have this functionality: "When user clicks on contacts button, should be able to see all contacts from device that are currently using that app. And also should able to see "invite" option for the contacts that are not that app."

How do I do this? So far I have installed contacts cordova plugin. What do I do next; apply some filter that will check who all are using same app from device contact list? Using Ionic 2 Framework.

Below is my code.

```js
HOME.TS

findContact(ev: any) {
  let fields: ContactFieldType[] = ['displayName'];

  const options = new ContactFindOptions();
  options.filter = ev.target.value;
  options.multiple = true;
  options.hasPhoneNumber = true;

  Contacts.find(fields, options).then((contacts) => {
    this.contactsfound = contacts;
    console.log(JSON.stringify(contacts[0]));
  });

  if (this.contactsfound.length == 0) {
    this.contactsfound.push({
      displayName: 'No Contacts found'
    });
  }
  this.search = true;
}
```

```html
Home.HTML

<ion-content>
  <ion-searchbar (ionInput)="findContact($event)" placeholder="Enter display name"></ion-searchbar>

  <ion-list [hidden]="!search">
    <ion-item *ngFor="let item of contactsfound">{{item.displayName}}</ion-item>
  </ion-list>

</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way of doing that is if you register each user that uses the app on your server. When a new user connects, you send his contact list to the server and check if one of them is already registered.

But before doing that, please check if there are any legal issues with this approach. I remember reading some news articles about this being illegal (because you are sending your contacts info to a server).

Comment: Thanks This is really helpful :).

Comment: You're welcome. If this answered your question, please consider accepting the answer or upvoting it. Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure how to do tht. I am new to stackoverflow.

Comment: On the left next to my answer there is a grey "tick" that you can click to accept an answer. You should accept/upvote answers if they resolve your problem.